# I created a virtual environment using venv and then selected that venv as my Python interpreter within VScode but building google-re2 still has errors

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to install Apache Airflow within my virtual environment but for some reason google-re2 wasn't installing correctly.
I'm on Python 3.11 and made sure my python interpreter is as well.

I ran

```
pip install google-re2
```

but now it's just giving errors

```
Building wheels for collected packages: google-re2
  Building wheel for google-re2 (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for google-re2 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [137 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      copying re2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      running build_ext
      building '_re2' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/chu/GamblingOdds/GamblingOdds/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c _re2.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/_re2.o -fvisibility=hidden
      In file included from _re2.cc:11
...
      warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
          using type = ISeq;
                       ^
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      17 warnings and 20 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for google-re2
      Failed to build google-re2
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for google-re2, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried to install pybind11 and pyre2 but it hasn't helped.

Comment: try run `pip cache purge && pip install --upgrade pip && pip install google-re2`

Comment: The same error happens. I was already on the latest version of pip.

Comment: Have you found a solution for your case?

Comment: I had to upgrade my MacOS and deleted and reinstalled Conda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after upgrading my MacOS and deleting and reinstalling Conda.